# How do I pass jquery result to highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery

Absolute novice here at JavaScript so please forgive any bad coding.

I have been working on a project using Highchart and wish to read the value of a file (actually read the file into an array and grab a specific value - I will use other values for other graphs).

With the help of others here I can now display the value of the array into HTML however I cannot pass this into the Highchart.

My prototype page (so you can see the output) can be found at

http://maccas.chickenkiller.com/1.html

The code is

```
<html debug="false">
    <head>
        <title>Adam's hacked up demo</title>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>

<script>

jQuery(function($){ // encapsulate jQuery
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:'livedata.txt',
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
            livedata = data.split(',');
            }
        });

    function drawGraph(phvalue) {
    var phvalue=livedata[3];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'gauge',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'live pH'
            },
                    pane: {
                startAngle: -150,
                endAngle: 150,
                background: [{
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#FFF'],
                            [1, '#333']
                        ]
                    },
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    outerRadius: '109%'
                }, {
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#333'],
                            [1, '#FFF']
                        ]
                    },
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    outerRadius: '107%'
                }, {
                    // default background
                }, {
                    backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    outerRadius: '105%',
                    innerRadius: '103%'
                }]
            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                min: 8,
                max: 9,

                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                minorTickWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 10,
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                minorTickColor: '#666',

                tickPixelInterval: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickLength: 10,
                tickColor: '#666',
                labels: {
                    step: 2,
                    rotation: 'auto'
                },
                plotBands: [{
                    from: 8,
                    to: 8.3,
                    color: '#55BF3B' // green
                }, {
                    from: 8.3,
                    to: 8.7,
                    color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
                }, {
                    from: 8.7,
                    to: 9,
                    color: '#DF5353' // red
                }]
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Current pH',
                data: [phvalue],
                tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' pH'
                }
            }]
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        drawGraph();
    });

});
</script> 

<body>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="container" style="width:90%; height:400px;"></div></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get the var phvalue to display in Highcharts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since ajax is asynchronous, you can draw the graph once the request is complete

```
jQuery(function($){ // encapsulate jQuery

    $.ajax(
        {
            url:'livedata.txt',
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                livedata = data.split(',');
                highcharts(livedata[3])
            }
        });


    function highcharts (phvalue) {
        $('#realtimeph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'gauge',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'live pH'
            },
            pane: {
                startAngle: -150,
                endAngle: 150,
                background: [{
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#FFF'],
                            [1, '#333']
                        ]
                    },
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    outerRadius: '109%'
                }, {
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#333'],
                            [1, '#FFF']
                        ]
                    },
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    outerRadius: '107%'
                }, {
                    // default background
                }, {
                    backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    outerRadius: '105%',
                    innerRadius: '103%'
                }]
            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                min: 8,
                max: 9,

                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                minorTickWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 10,
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                minorTickColor: '#666',

                tickPixelInterval: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickLength: 10,
                tickColor: '#666',
                labels: {
                    step: 2,
                    rotation: 'auto'
                },
                plotBands: [{
                    from: 8,
                    to: 8.3,
                    color: '#55BF3B' // green
                }, {
                    from: 8.3,
                    to: 8.7,
                    color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
                }, {
                    from: 8.7,
                    to: 9,
                    color: '#DF5353' // red
                }]
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Current pH',
                data: [phvalue],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' pH'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated the code as you suggested but now get an error.  According to the output it's to do with http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13.  Could it have been to do with the fact you used the var "highcharts"?

Comment: it is because you have not provided any div to render the chart

Comment: under `chart: {` add a property `renderTo: ''` and pass the `id` of the element to which the chart has to be rendered to as shown in this example http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRs9U/1/

Comment: Added as per your fiddle but it still didn't work ()NOTE: It was graph a value of 0 prior to changing the Ajax - maybe by mistake more than anything.

Comment: another problem was the script was not executed in dom ready, try the update

Comment: Also there is no element with id `realtimeph` in the page

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help so far.  I'm not really sure what you mean by "not executed in dom ready, try the update".  I have also changed the renderTo: 'realtimeph' and also updated the <div> at ni the html section.

Comment: Thanks - but data still not passing to Highchart.

Answer (score 0):

This was surprisingly complicated.  You want:

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[0].update(x)
```

where `x` is the number you want to update with

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand where I want to put this - I have created http://jsfiddle.net/vNZmf/  Are you able to edit this?

Comment: At whatever point in the code you want the update to happen.  If you want the page to load with the data in place and then not change until the page is refreshed then you should use the asynchronous method described by Arun P Johny above.  If you want to change the values in the chart at some time after the chart has been created then you can use the line of code I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks - issue is I can' get either method to load the variable.  Highcharts works fine is I add a value (eg. 8.2) in the data but it won't let me use a variable that contains the data.

Comment: are you certain that the variable contains the value you think it does?  try adding a console.log statement (e.g. console.log(myvariable);  The value should turn up in you Javascript Console.